# How to read column value generically from a datatable in .NET without explicitly specifying the data type and column name

Tags: generics, types, datatable

I want to read column value from a datatable without explicitly specifying the data type and column name.

E.g.

```
int carId = CarTable.Rows[i].Field<int>("CarId");  //this requires the data type and column name.

string name= CarTable.Rows[i].Field<string>("Name");
```

I want to read to carId without explicitly specifying the data type and column name.

Will it be easier if I want the return type of all columns be string type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're thinking of using the column's position rather than its name, you should be able to do :

```
Object colvalue = CarTable.Rows[i].Items[colpos];
```

Comment: Thanks, Will that work for string, and other data type? How do I get value from object type?

Comment: Is there a way to detect the datatype and assign it to a variable of its type?

Comment: Yes, you need to enumerate through the CarTable.Columns collection which will give you the data type information on each column. So CarTable.Columns[colpos] will give you the info you need to work out the data type of CarTable.Rows[i].Items[colpos]